# List is not being updated in React after change in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen plenty of similar questions, but somehow the usual answers don't work in my case.

I have a simple list of items being loaded from an API, see screenshot. When I press the 'Set cover' button, I expect the items to be refreshed and the 'Set cover' to appear on the other item. The API cleans all `cover` attributes and sets it on the item that is selected.

This is the code for the list:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ImageItem from "./ImageItem";

export default function ImageForm({reviewId}) {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    function setCover(id) {
        const newList = items.map((item) => {
            return {
                ...item,
                cover: (item.id === id),
            };
        });

        console.log('newlist', newList);
        setItems(newList);
    }

    const loadList = () => {
        fetch("/api/review/" + reviewId + "/images")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log('useEffect', json);
                setItems(json);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadList();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col col-sm-6">
                    {items.map((data) => {
                        return <ImageItem key={data.id}
                                          data={data}
                                          reload={loadList}
                                          makeCover2={setCover}
                        />;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );

}

And this is the code for the item Component:
```

And this is the code for the item Component:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {Dropdown} from "react-bootstrap";

export default function ImageItem({data, remove, reload, makeCover2}) {
    const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(data);

    const makeCover = async function (item) {
        axios.post('/api/image/' + imageData.id + '/setcover').then(res => {
            if (res.data.errors) {
                console.error(res.data.errors);
            } else {
                makeCover2(imageData.id);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    }

    return (<div className="row my-2 py-2 image-item">

        <div className="col p-0 m-0">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <img className="img-fluid" alt="" src={'/upload/img/' + imageData.image_name}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col text-end">
                    <Dropdown>
                        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">Actions</Dropdown.Toggle>
                        <Dropdown.Menu>
                            <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}>Change comment</Dropdown.Item>
                            {!imageData.cover && <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={makeCover}>Set cover</Dropdown.Item>}
                            <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => remove(imageData.id)}>Delete</Dropdown.Item>
                        </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>)

}
```

I tried 2 approaches:

- Call a function `makeCover2` that updates all items in the list after the API is done updating the rows and..
- Call a reload function that just calls the `loadList` function, getting all items from the API again.

In both cases, the `Set cover` dropdown option stays on the same item in the list. But it should jump to the other item after clicking it. What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(data);
```

You've copied the `data` prop into a state variable. The value in `data` is only checked on the very first render to set the initial value of `imageData`. Changes to `data` afterwards will have no effect on `imageData`.

I see no reason for the state to exist, so i recommend you fix this by deleting the state, and using the prop directly:

```
export default function ImageItem({ data, remove, reload, makeCover2 }) {
  const makeCover = async function (item) {
    axios
      .post("/api/image/" + data.id + "/setcover")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.errors) {
          console.error(res.data.errors);
        } else {
          makeCover2(data.id);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    // ...
    <img className="img-fluid" alt="" src={'/upload/img/' + data.image_name}/>
    // ...
    {!data.cover && (
      <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={makeCover}>
        Set cover
      </Dropdown.Item>
    )}
    <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => remove(data.id)}>
      Delete
    </Dropdown.Item>
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really clear on the mechanics of the useState() defaults, but this explains it. I'm using the props now directly as suggested, and that works.